# Чтение объединенных ячеек

Tags: java, apache-poi

Как прочитать значение объединенной ячейки или определить, что она объединенная?

Проблема в том, что при чтении только первой ячейки из всех с ней объединенных можно получить значение, все остальные возвращают пустоту.

Comment: CellRangeAddress cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(value.getFirstRow(), value.getLastRow(), value.getFirstCol(), value.getLastCol());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вохможно, это поможет. 
Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664977/how-to-read-from-merged-cells-of-excel-in-java-using-apache-poi)

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        //For each row, iterate through all the columns
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

        outer:
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            //will iterate over the Merged cells
            for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
                CellRangeAddress region = sheet.getMergedRegion(i); //Region of merged cells

                int colIndex = region.getFirstColumn(); //number of columns merged
                int rowNum = region.getFirstRow();      //number of rows merged
                //check first cell of the region
                if (rowNum == cell.getRowIndex() && colIndex == cell.getColumnIndex()) {
                    System.out.println(sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colIndex).getStringCellValue());
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            //the data in merge cells is always present on the first cell. All other cells(in merged region) are considered blank
            if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK || cell == null) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Да, спасибо) Я что-то подобное на PHP видел, там это так же делается. Интересно почему создатели библиотеки, приняли такое решение, намного логичнее было бы возвращать одинаковые значение для объединённых ячеек...